# vuetify button with router link for navigation bar

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am working on a website and I wanted to have the v-btn's styling be set to the active link, I got it kinda working but the background of the button doesn't change correctly, there is just a highlight being applied to the text

```
<v-btn active-class="active" router-link to="/"><v-card></v-card>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
</v-btn>
.v-btn .router-link-exact-active{
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #888888;
  font-size: xx-large;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things you can do to make this easier to handle:

1. you can use `v-btn` inside `router-link` like this:

   ```
   <router-link to="/profile">
    <v-btn class="mx-4 white--text" elevation="2" x-large rounded color="deep-purple darken-1" to="/profile">
          Profile
    </v-btn>
   </router-link> 

   .router-link-exact-active .v-btn {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #888888;
    font-size: xx-large;
    }
   ```
2. you can use `router-link` `tag attribute` like this:

   ```
       <router-link to="/feed" tag="v-btn">
        <v-btn class="mx-4 white--text" elevation="2" x-large rounded color="deep-purple darken-1">
          Feed
        </v-btn>
      </router-link>
   ```
3. you can use `v-btn`  with `to` props like this:

   ```
      <v-btn class="mx-4 white--text" elevation="2" x-large rounded color="deep-purple darken-1" to="/feed">
        Feed
      </v-btn>
   ```